# Can we use input step inside parallel block of Jenkins declarative pipeline written in Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have three pipelines that I want to run in parallel but whether to run either of the pipeline or not should be taken as a manual input. I have tried the following code:

```
stage('Stage 1') {
                    echo 'Stage One'    
                }
stage('Stage 2') {
parallel (
           'TestAndroidPipeline': { build('TestAndroidPipeline') },
           'Input for step one': { input('Input for step one') },
           'TestiOSPipeline': { build('TestiOSPipeline') },
           'Input for step two': { input('Input for step two') },
           'TestWinPipeline': { build('TestWinPipeline') }
         )
}
stage('Stage 3'){
    echo 'Stage Three'
}
```

With this the stage is displaying paused UI but it is triggering the "TestiOSPipeline" and "TestWinPipeline" pipelines. On clicking "Proceed" option for the 2 input steps, third stage is triggered.

I want to use the manual input twice in stage 2. Is it possible to use manual input in parallel block? Is there any other option to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by manual input?